# porting from wince to vx works

Tags: windows-ce, vxworks

currently i am working on a project in which i have to port a code from wince 6.0 to vx works...
but there are some portions of code which contains registry functions of windows and vx works  do not t have registry concepts and do not support it...
how to port these registry code in Vx-works....how can i create an alternative of registry in Vx-works ....? can i use XML for this...?

I am implementing this in c++ and i am thinking to create directories and store registry like information in the form of files(.txt)..

give me any suggestions how to do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is not good IDEA here, because you are not going to send/receive data belong app and an external resource, I thing a customized-format (encrypted) file, in a no visible path (temp, resources) would be nice.

also you would embed the info inside the execution file, but be careful about this, that would hurt your file.

Comment: ok can i create a folder tree and then files in it and then values in the files..?

Comment: it would be in many manner, if you have some policies about for hiding data or security, you need to store it in some where secure (at-least somewhere that user cannot find easily). also about the tree structure you would go for folders, or specify the tree level with file names, for example, user.software.ms,winnt.run.xyz

Comment: my pleasure, just check my account [here](arashmd.blogspot.com), you would contact me via my contact form in my blog :D

Comment: i didnt find ur mail id in ur blog...@Arash give me ur mail id

Comment: wow, this is not good idea, share something like email id here, but it's okay buddy 
arash [dot] dx [at] googlemail [dot] com

Comment: have u ever worked on windows registry.... i mean created registry files anytime....without using predefined functions...

Comment: for example RegCreateKeyEx() creates a reg key..... i want to define a function which does the exact of the above function

Comment: first you need to have a specific format to replace with registry, it would be in folder/file format, or in a single file, or in multiple files, it could be the basic IO operations.